# How to invoke Dropzone (JS) from Java?

Tags: javascript, java, dropzone.js, htmlunit

I am doing some web scraping tasks and one of the pages includes the option to upload some photos through Dropzone.

My scraping is done from Java + HTMLUnit but I am stuck in the process of adding photos to the JS Dropzone component. How do I invoke the code to upload files?

I have tried different options but I am quite new to Java+HTML+JS interaction. This just does not work (undefined):

```
ScriptResult result = currentPage.executeJavaScript("Dropzone.addFile()"); 
    result.getNewPage();
```

This shows a lot of information about methods but does not show much related to the script included in the code below (function ver, for example) but only methods defined above this code (to manage cookies and some information messages from the web):

```
ScriptResult result = currentPage.executeJavaScript(""
            + "for (var id in this) {"
            + "try {"
            + "console.log(id + \": \" + this[id].toString());"
            + "} catch (err) {"
            + "}"
            + "}");
    
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(600000);
```

Thanks in advance,

This is my HTML important code:

```
<div class="paso">
    <img width="40" height="40" src="https://static.milanuncios.com/imagenes/4-anuncios.gif" title="INSERTAR ANUNCIOS">
    Por último, si lo deseas puedes insertar fotos.
    <br>Los anuncios con foto llaman más la atención de posibles compradores.
</div>

<script src="https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/exif.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone-exif-extension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.milanuncios.com/css/fotos/dropzone.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ver(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = '10000';
    }

    Dropzone.options.photoUploader = {
        init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;
            this.__photoId = 0;
            this.__uploadingPhotos = false;
            this.__isPhotoUploadDone = false;
            this.__errorMessagePrevious = "";

            this.on("thumbnail", function(file){
                ExifExtension.applyRotation(file);
            });

            this.on("success", function() {
                if(this.__uploadingPhotos)
                    this.processQueue();
            });

            this.options.url = function(files) {
                if (files.length !== 1) {
                    alert("Error interno 5690, por favor intentalo más tarde");
                    return;
                }

                var localPhotoId = ++myDropzone.__photoId;

                                    return "/images/upload-image-auth.php?&idanuncio=239861376&clave=V1hEUQ%3D%3D&numfoto="+localPhotoId;
            };

            this.on("processing", function() {
                ver('espera');
                document.getElementById('upload-all').disabled = true;
            });

            this.on("drop", function() {
                this.__errorMessagePrevious = "";
            });

            this.on("error", function(file, errorMessage) {
                console.log("error: ", errorMessage);
                if (file.status == "error") {
                    if (!file.accepted) {
                        this.removeFile(file);
                    } else {
                        errorMessage = this.options.dictResponseError;
                    }
                    if (errorMessage != this.__errorMessagePrevious) {
                        this.__errorMessagePrevious = errorMessage;
                        alert(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                if(this.__uploadingPhotos)
                    this.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
                this.__isPhotoUploadDone = true;
                window.location = 'http://www.milanuncios.com/publicado/?idanuncio=239861376&contra=WXDQ';
            });

            var submitButton = document.getElementById("upload-all");
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                myDropzone.__uploadingPhotos = true;
                if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length == 0) {
                    myDropzone.emit("queuecomplete", "");
                }
                else {
                    ver('espera');
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                }
            });

            var dropArea = document.getElementById("dropArea");
            dropArea.addEventListener("click", function() {
                // Clean all the previous error messages
                myDropzone.__errorMessagePrevious = "";
            });
        },
        paramName: "uploadFile1",
        parallelUploads: 1,
        maxFiles: 9,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        autoProcessQueue: false, // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 5,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        thumbnailWidth: 100,
        thumbnailHeight: 100,
        imageWidth: 800,
        imageHeight: 800,
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/gif ,image/png",
        imageQuality: 0.8,
        dictDefaultMessage: "<strong>Arrastra tus fotos aquí <br/> o <br/> selecciónalas de tu equipo</strong><div class=\"btnAddPhoto\">Añadir fotos</div>",
        dictFallbackMessage: "Tu navegador no soporta arrastrar fotos directamente.",
        dictFallbackText: "Utiliza el método antiguo para subir fotos.",
        dictFileTooBig: "La fotos es demasiado grande.",
        dictInvalidFileType: "Formato no permitido. Asegúrate que tus fotos son JPG, JPEG, GIF o PNG.",
        dictResponseError: "Error al subir tus fotos. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.",
        dictCancelUpload: "Cancelar",
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "¿Estás seguro que deseas cancelar la subida?",
        dictRemoveFile: "Eliminar",
        dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "¿Estás seguro que deseas eliminar esta foto?",
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: "No puedes subir más de 9 fotos."
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (Dropzone && Dropzone.instances[0] && !Dropzone.instances[0].__isPhotoUploadDone) {
            return "¿Realmente quieres irte sin subir tus fotos?";
        }
    };
</script>

<div class="insertadonCol">
    <div class="photoUploaderWrapper">
        <div class="subida" id="espera">
            <br><br>
            Espere por favor...<br><br>
            <img src="https://static.milanuncios.com/imagenes/waiting.gif">
            <br><br>
            <div class="normal">
                Este proceso, puede tardar unos segundos.
                <br>
                <br>
                Gracias,
                <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MilAnuncios.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="dropArea">
            <form action="/images/upload-image-auth.php" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" drop-zone="" id="photoUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div class="dz-default dz-message"><span><strong>Arrastra tus fotos aquí <br> o <br> selecciónalas de tu equipo</strong><div class="btnAddPhoto">Añadir fotos</div></span></div></form>
        </div>

        <br><br>

        <div class="uploadBtnBox">
            <button id="upload-all" class="uploadBtn">Finalizar publicación</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to isolate a minimal test case as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html).

Comment: @AhmedAshour I have tried everything I know of but the problem is not JS at all. The fact that I cannot/dont know how to access some of the JS is the problem. I have tried different browsers compatibility from HtmlUnit and followed their web suggestions to no avail... just need to figure out how to say JS "hey, this is the file I want to upload" and let HTMLUnit and JS do the magic as it does... but dont know how to start.

Comment: Then please provide a complete test case, so others can reproduce your issue.